# How to calculate statistics over sequences of non zeros in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing sequences as follows:

```
r1=c(0,0,0,1.2,5,0.5,3.3,0,0,2.1,0.7,1,3.3,0,0,0,0,2.5,4.2,1,5.2,0,0,0,0)
r2=c(0,0,3.5,5.1,2.5,0,0,0,0.6,1.7,1.6,1.2,1.6,0,0,0,0,1.5,1.8,1.5,0,0,0,0,0)
r=as.data.frame(cbind(r1,r2))
```

My actual data contain more columns and rows. For each column, I'd like to get the minimum/maximum/average (basic statistics) of the maximum of each sequence of non-zero values. That means that, considering one column, I extract the maximum value of each one of its sequences of successive non-0 values and then I perform the statistics over them.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Here I've written some functions to break your vectors into the individual runs, extract the values you want (the maxes within the runs), and then apply the basic statistics you are asking for.  There may be a more elegant or more efficient method.

```
r1=c(0,0,0,1.2,5,0.5,3.3,0,0, 2.1,0.7,1,3.3,0,0,0,0,2.5,4.2,1,5.2,0,0,0,0)
r2=c(0,0,3.5,5.1,2.5,0,0,0,0.6,1.7,1.6,1.2,1.6,0,0,0,0,1.5,1.8,1.5,0,0,0,0,0)
r=as.data.frame(cbind(r1,r2))

my.stats.fun <- function(col){
  # sub fuctions
  remove.successive.0s <- function(col){ 
    col  <- c(col, 0)
    i0   <- which(col==0)
    i00  <- i0[which(diff(i0)==1)]
    col2 <- col[-i00]
    if(col2[1]==0){ col2 <- col2[-1] }  # pops first 0
    return(col2)
  }
  run.indicator <- function(col){
    i0   <- which(col==0)
    lr   <- length(i0)
    runs <- rep(1:lr, times=c(i0-c(0,i0[-lr])))
    col  <- col[-i0]
    runs <- runs[-i0]
    return(list(values=col, index=runs))
  }
  basic.stats <- function(maxes){ 
    return(c(min=min(maxes), ave=mean(maxes), max=max(maxes)))
  }

  # apply functions
  col   <- remove.successive.0s(col)
  runs  <- run.indicator(col)
  maxes <- aggregate(runs$values, by=list(runs$index), max)[,2]
  stats <- basic.stats(maxes)
  return(stats)
}
sapply(r, my.stats.fun)
#      r1       r2
# min 3.3 1.700000
# ave 4.5 2.866667
# max 5.2 5.100000
```